# Drawing animation to only run on scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, svg, scroll

I have an icon drawn when i scroll down the page and undrawn when i scroll up.
I would like to make it draw only when i scroll down and stay this way for the rest of the session.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $dashOffset = $(".path").css("stroke-dashoffset");
  $(window).scroll(function() {
  var $percentageComplete = (($(window).scrollTop() / ($("html").height() - $(window).height())) * 100);
  var $newUnit = parseInt($dashOffset, 10);
  var $offsetUnit = $percentageComplete * ($newUnit / 100);
  $(".path").css("stroke-dashoffset", $newUnit - $offsetUnit);});

 var $bg = $(".background")
 $(document).scroll(function(){
  $bg.css({transform: $(this).scrollTop()<1 ? "scale":"scale(1,1)"});
 });
```

});

Comment: can you please full code or fiddle or SO snippet?

Comment: Check out the animation on codepen: https://codepen.io/nikches/pen/vKKxyB